# tell a batch file the working directory without using change directory (cd) command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've a batch file **merge.bat**. It's for merging all files in a specific folder to a single file with a *new line* between each file's content. To tell *merge.bat* which folder I want it to apply merging on, I use the *change directory* (*CD*) command first, then open *merge.bat* using **cmd command**. I'm looking for a way to tell *merge.bat* where are my files, without using *change directory* (*CD*) first (Something like **cmd command 1**).

**merge.bat**

```
del merged.txt

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    type %%I >> merged.tmp
    echo. >> merged.tmp
)

ren merged.tmp merged.txt
```

**cmd command**

```
cd "My/Files/Directory/"
"My/Batch/File/Directory/merge.bat"
```

**cmd command 1**

```
"My/Batch/File/Directory/merge.bat" "My/Files/Directory/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Retrieve folder to process from batch file arguments
    set "targetFolder=%~f1"

    rem If we do not get a folder, use current one
    if not defined targetFolder set "targetFolder=%cd%"

    rem Change to the indicated folder
    pushd "%targetFolder%" && (

        rem Clear existing file
        2>nul del merged.txt

        rem Output all txt files into temporary file
        (for %%a in (*.txt) do (
            type "%%a"
            echo(
        )) > merged.tmp

        rem Rename temporary file to final name
        ren merged.tmp merged.txt

        rem Return to the previous active directory
        popd
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, on Windows the directory separator is `\` and not `/`.

Second, the arguments passed to a batch file can be used in the batch file with `%0` (batch file name), `%1` (first parameter), `%2` (second parameter), ... `%*` (all parameters not including batch file name).

For understanding the usage of parameters, open a command prompt window, execute there the command `call /?` and read entirely all help pages displayed very carefully.

Batch code for `merge.bat`:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" pushd "%~1"
del merged.txt 2>nul

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    type %%I >>merged.tmp
    echo.>>merged.tmp
)

ren merged.tmp merged.txt
if not "%~1" == "" popd
```

Run in a command prompt window `pushd /?` for details on this command as well as for **popd**.

Answer (score 0):

This code help you:

```
    @echo off
    if "%~1" == "" (set path_to="%~dp0") else (set path_to="%~1")
    if exist "%path_to%merged.txt" del %path_to%merged.txt
    for %%I in (%path_to%*.txt) do (
        type %%I >> %path_to%merged.tmp
        echo. >> %path_to%merged.tmp
    )
    ren %path_to%merged.tmp merged.txt
```

if the argument passed, the script uses the folder from which you launched